# [iOS]application crash

Tags: ios

in my Mac iPhone simulator (iPhone simulator 4.0) i run my app without problem, but when i change it to another Mac which runs iPhone simulator 4.2 it crushes on a button click somewhere in the app, could the version of the debugger (4.0 and 4.2) be the cause of a potential crash ? thx in advance :))

**EDIT**

this is the code i have doubt it may cause crash 'cause i use in it a UIPickerView code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ((UILabel *)[[[[[[switchCommerce subviews] lastObject] subviews] objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:0]).text = @"oui";
        ((UILabel *)[[[[[[switchCommerce subviews] lastObject] subviews] objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:1]).text = @"non";
        ((UILabel *)[[[[[[switchStationDeLavage subviews] lastObject] subviews] objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:0]).text = @"oui";
        ((UILabel *)[[[[[[switchStationDeLavage subviews] lastObject] subviews] objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:1]).text = @"non";
        [rayonDeRechercheSlider setValue:35 animated:YES];
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        CGAffineTransform transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,480);
        pickerViewTypeCarburant.transform=transform;
        pickerViewNomStation.transform=transform;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [super viewDidLoad];
        typeCarburantTextField.delegate=self;
        nomDeStationTextField.delegate=self;
        pickerArrayTypeCarburant=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Sans Plomb 95",@"Gazole",@"Super Gazole",@"GNV",@"Sans Plomb 98",@"SP95-E10",@"E85",nil];
        pickerArrayNomStation=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"TOTAL",@"SHELL",@"ESSO",@"CARREFOUR",@"BP",@"AGIP",@"CASINO",@"LECLERC",@"AUCHAN",@"ELF",@"AVIA",@"SUPER U",nil];//added
    }
```

Comment: Epic use of square braces there.

Comment: What error message does the debugger show on crashing? Could you include a backtrace?

Comment: hi, what you mean please by : "Epic use of square braces there." ??

Comment: @Malek: Just meant that there are a lot of nested calls where you set your `UILabel` text. Nothing wrong with it, just made me smile :)

Comment: Hi, thx for your answers, i googled somewhere and i found a discussion which talk about memory managment and crushes , could it be a lack of management especially for the mutable arrays ??

Comment: @Malek: I presume the arrays "`pickerArrayTypeCarburant`" and "`pickerArrayNomStation`" are properties of your class?

Comment: Hi, this how i declared them in the .h file of the class :    NSMutableArray        *pickerArrayTypeCarburant;
NSMutableArray        *pickerArrayNomStation;

Comment: it's not properties, if iam wrong, how should i declare them please??

Comment: @Malek: Since you need to be able to retain arrays using these instance variables, I would say that you should declare them as properties. You may benefit from reading Apple's documentation on the Objective_C Programming Language: [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1) (see the section on "Declared Properties"). I have edited my answer below to show how you should probably declare your array ivars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential problem in your code is that you appear to be assigning to your mutable array properties (`pickerArrayTypeCarburant` & `pickerArrayNomStation`) without using the `self.` notation. What this means is that the arrays are being assigned without using `retain` semantics (presuming that your `@property` declaration for the arrays is told to use `retain`).

The effect of this is that when you try to access this array later in your code you will find that the array has not been retained, and you will likely be receiving some kind of memory warning. Try this instead:

```
self.pickerArrayTypeCarburant=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Sans Plomb 95",@"Gazole",@"Super Gazole",@"GNV",@"Sans Plomb 98",@"SP95-E10",@"E85",nil];
self.pickerArrayNomStation=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"TOTAL",@"SHELL",@"ESSO",@"CARREFOUR",@"BP",@"AGIP",@"CASINO",@"LECLERC",@"AUCHAN",@"ELF",@"AVIA",@"SUPER U",nil];
```

It's hard to tell if that will solve your problem since I don't know what error is being thrown, however if it is memory related then that could be the culprit.

To be sure, you could run your app in Instruments and see if there are any leaks or allocations where there shouldn't be.

**EDIT:**

In response to your comment regarding properties, your header file should probably declare your NSMutableArrays like this:

YourClass.h

```
@interface YourClass {
    NSMutableArray *pickerArrayTypeCarburant;
    NSMutableArray *pickerArrayNomStation;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *pickerArrayTypeCarburant;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *pickerArrayNomStation;


// Any method names here...


@end
```

And at the top of your `.m` file, just underneath the `@implementation` line:

```
@synthesize pickerArrayTypeCarburant, pickerArrayNomStation;
```

The `@synthesize` part will automatically create the required accessors and mutators for your properties, based on the information you provide on the lines with `@property`. In this case, I have defined that the properties should use retain semantics, which means that when you assign a value to your property using `self.` (i.e. `self.pickerArrayNomStation = anArray;`) the array you assign to it will automatically be retained by your property. Make sure you include the `self.` when assigning to a property that uses retain, as this is what tells it to use the generated mutator method, rather than just assigning to the instance variable without retaining.

By the way, make sure that when you generate retained properties in this way that you call `[myProperty release];` in the `dealloc` method, and (assuming your class is a view controller...) `self.myProperty = nil` in your `viewDidUnload` method. This ensures that any retained objects are released properly when your views and view controllers are no longer needed.

If you need further information about this stuff, Apple's documentation is your friend. I found their programming guides really helpful when I was starting out. The guide I linked you in my comment under your answer is a good one to start with.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT 2**

Not sure if this will help, but I have sometimes found that assigning arrays in this way is a little safer... at the bottom of the ViewDidLoad method where you are assigning to your array property, change the code to this:

```
NSMutableArray *newArrayTypeCarburant = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Sans Plomb 95",@"Gazole",@"Super Gazole",@"GNV",@"Sans Plomb 98",@"SP95-E10",@"E85",nil];
NSMutableArray *newArrayNomStation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"TOTAL",@"SHELL",@"ESSO",@"CARREFOUR",@"BP",@"AGIP",@"CASINO",@"LECLERC",@"AUCHAN",@"ELF",@"AVIA",@"SUPER U",nil];
self.pickerArrayTypeCarburant = newArrayTypeCarburant;
self.pickerArrayNomStation = newArrayNomStation;
[newArrayTypeCarburant release];
[newArrayNomStation release];
```

Comment: i will check it and i tell you what will happen, please stay uptodate with my post :)))) thx

Comment: when i use the self statement it give me error :   error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found

Comment: @Malek: I've edited my answer now to include information on how you should assign your property so that it generates the setter for you, and causes your property to use `retain` when assigning values to it.

Comment: Hi StuDev, i have understand your idea and i did as you said, everything was ok, but the crash is always caused in my boss's Mac, he tolds me he has no back trace messages !!!!!!! please help me,all memory management is ok, and the accessing to that view which have the code above (from any view) results in crush, the big doubt is in the ViewDidLoad method because the crash is when the view is about appearing, am i right ??

Comment: @Malek: There should be some information somewhere regarding the crash - what exactly is happening when the app crashes? Have you tried typing "bt" into the debugging console to show a backtrace? Else try setting NSZombieEnabled to "YES" in your apps environment variables - these types of bad access crashes can show no console messages. I've also added another edit to my answer above - try it out. Without knowing more about the crash, there's not a lot more I can suggest - have you tried setting breakpoints to find the exact point of the crash?

Comment: what can i say..million thx friend, i will check it out and tell you as soon as possible :) please be there, thx